# how to handle asynchronously: function C depending on function B depending on function A

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I have three functions that all work with data from a global object. This global object gets filled with data from a local array in one function and with data from an ajax request with the second function. The third function relies on the data in the object, so the ajax request must have been completed.

I believe I am misunderstanding callbacks. Here's what I do:

```
var currentCharacter = {}

// this function gets the local data and then calls the second function
function loadData(getMarvelData) {
   // do things to fill currentCharacter
   getMarvelData(); // this is the callback to the next function (no ?)
}

// this function performs the ajax request, then calls the third function
function getMarvelData(getGoogleMap) {
   // do ajax request and add stuff to currentCharacter
   getGoogleMap(); // this is the callback to the final function (no ?)
}

function getGoogleMap() {
   // do Google Map related stuff with data from currentCharacter
}
```

I thought setting a function as an argument of another function and then executing it would make the function dependent on the other before it continues. Clearly I still misunderstand callbacks after trying to make it work for a week now. As it is, the getMarvelData function doesn't even get called because I never see the alert popup and the currentCharacter object only has data from the loadData function.

Could somebody show the correct approach for my code, or if my approach of making these three functions is even the right one for this scenario.

The full repository is available at: https://github.com/ChaMbuna/Marvel-Map
V0.9 was actually working but the ajax call was set to run synchronous (it still is btw) Since then I've been overhauling my code to make it work asynchronously and to remove all jQuery (this is a Udacity project and removing jQuery was suggested by an instructor).

Appreciate the help

Comment: Those functions you are calling "back" are *parameters*. However, you're never *passing* any arguments there!

Comment: Also, you need to call them from the asynchronous part of your code (the `onreadystatechange` handler), not just at the end of the function!

Comment: Since you're depending on the ajax request completing, you can use the success function in the ajax call to execute the other function(s) that depend on it completing first.

Comment: Bergi, I like the onreadystatechange comment, it is a way I haven't explored yet. I will try working with that.

Comment: @Bergi  the `onreadystatechange` was a great first step. I have simplified my code a bit in hopes I understand things. I've consolidated `loadData` and `getMarvelData` into one function `loadData`. in the `onreadystatechange` handler I've added a console.log to check my `currentCharracter` which has all the info I need for the google geocoder to work. When I then run `getGoogleMap()` inside of the `onreadystatechange` handler, the screen refreshes but the map doesn't update. Do I somehow need to pass the `getGoogleMap` function to the handler before I execute it?

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to put a comment, but a wild guess, you should remove the argument in loadData&getMarvelData or actually pass a function in calls to those function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameters correctly. 
Try this:

```
var currentCharacter = {}
loadData(getMarvelData, getGoogleMap);

function loadData(f1, f2) {
   // do sth.
   f1(f2);
}

function getMarvelData(f2) {
   // do sth.
   f2(); 
}

function getGoogleMap() {
   // do sth.
}
```

I havn't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: No. You should only have a single callback parameter.

Comment: And how do you call the third function?

Comment: By doing `loadData(function(data) { getMarvelData(data, getGoogleMap); })`

Comment: I've tried this but it has the same effect as my original code. It executes the first part only. Bergi, none of these functions take arguments, they all use the global object currentCharacter as their 'workbench'.

Comment: Maybe the problem ist, that AJAX is asynchronous? Set the synchron parameter=true and the code will be executed synchronously: xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php",false);

Comment: I don't want it to execute synchronously, that's the whole reason I've been under stress for a week now trying to get it to work :-)

Comment: Ok, use the onreadystatechange function like Bergi said. When you dont have to execute JavaScript after your function call, you could execute it  synchronously

Comment: @Max from what I've been told and found, a callback will fix this by having one function to depend on the execution of another. Somehow this is different from halting your entire app, as supposedly it continues code execution but I am having a hard time to understand how this works. Either way, it is a strict necessity for this project to run asynchronously, so it must be possible.